# Asymptotic evaluation of an oscillatory integral

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, oscillatory-integral

First of all, I am a physicist, so please excuse me if I make basic mistakes in the following, I will try to be as rigorous as possible. In my research, I recently came across the following integral for $\Omega>0$:

$\psi(t,\Omega)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathrm{d}\omega\,\Phi(\omega)\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\omega t}-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\Omega t}}{\omega-\Omega}$

$\Phi$ being a smooth and integrable function. Typically, I have to deal with functions of the kind:

$\Phi(\omega)\underset{\omega\to0^+}{\longrightarrow}0$ and $\Phi(\omega)\underset{\omega\to+\infty}{\simeq}K\omega^\alpha\mathrm{e}^{-\omega}$

I would like to estimate $\psi(t,\Omega)$ for $t\to+\infty$.

I tried to rewrite the integrand as follows:

$\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\omega t}-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\Omega t}}{\omega-\Omega}=-\frac{2\mathrm{i}\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\frac{\omega+\Omega}{2}t}}{\omega-\Omega}\sin(\frac{\omega-\Omega}{2}t)$

I then used the approximation (fairly widely used in my field, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Oscillatory_integrals):

$\frac{\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}\underset{t\to+\infty}{\simeq}\pi\delta(\omega)$, $\delta$ being the Dirac distribution

That would lead me to (warning, here comes the lack of mathematical rigor):

$\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\omega t}-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\Omega t}}{\omega-\Omega}\underset{t\to+\infty}{\simeq}-2\mathrm{i}\pi\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\frac{\omega+\Omega}{2}t}\delta(\omega-\Omega)=-2\mathrm{i}\pi\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\Omega t}\delta(\omega-\Omega)$

This yields:

$\psi(t,\Omega)\underset{t\to+\infty}{\simeq}-2\mathrm{i}\pi\Phi(\Omega)\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\Omega t}$

I tried to perform some numerical calculations with Wolfram Mathematica to check this result, and, if the oscillation induced by the factor $\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\Omega t}$ seems present, the modulus of $\psi(t,\Omega)$ does not seem to follow the above approximation.

Since I am no expert in this kind of questions, I don't know how to find information that could help me with this question. If someone has an idea or a good reference to advise it would be of great help to me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does $\Phi$ have a meromorphic extension to $\mathbb{C}$ (i.e. can it be defined on $\mathbb{C}$ and only fail to be complex-differentiable at finitely many points)? I ask because without $\Phi$ this can be evaluated using the residue theorem.

Comment: Barring such methodology, your approach fails because you haven't fully encapsulated all the "rapidly oscillatory" bits into your Dirac delta limit: you still have that $e^{-i \frac{\omega+\Omega}{2} t}$. So you can't immediately restrict attention to $\omega=\Omega$ because of that. Perhaps you can split the integral into a neighborhood of $\Omega$ and the two sides thereof, perform a Taylor asymptotic near $\omega=\Omega$, and then split the numerator elsewhere?

Comment: Alternately you could try to follow the method of stationary phase: if $\Phi$ has just one sign then the phase should actually be a smooth function (even at $\omega=\Omega$) so it should work nicely.

Comment: is the rotating wave approximation valid for your problem of interest?

Comment: furthermore, can you get the correct asymptotics for the sumplest function which satifies your boundary condtions, namely $\Psi(\omega)=\omega e^{-\omega }$?

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I'll add some details about function $\Phi$. The function is positive for $\omega>0$. As for an extension of $\Phi$ to the complex plane, I think the resulting function is not meromorphic (there seems to be a branch cut along the positive real axis with continuity from below actually).

Comment: The problem I face with the method of stationary phase is that the second derivative of the phase is precisely 0 because $\Phi$ is positive along the postive real line. But maybe I misunderstood your suggestion.

Comment: To answer to tired, I am precisely trying to find an exact solution for my problem of interest. The function $\psi(t,\Omega)$ I described appears in my exact solution, I am looking for a long-time estimation of it in order to derive steady-state properties for my system. The goal is then to compare this solution with other ones obtained with standard physical approximations. Finally, I indeed tried to compute some asymptotics for $\Phi(\omega)=\omega e^{-\omega}$, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: the ''simple case'' i mentioned can be done exactly in terms of so called exponential integrals with well known asymtotics.  this should give you a hint what to expect in the general case (at least if $\phi$ is entire) the case with poles can be handeled by explixitly taking the residues in some specific sector of the complex plane into account. If we have a branch cut at the negative axis i have to think a bit, but my guess is that it doesn't change the problem drastically...

Comment: what kind of model we are talking about? your integral make me think of something from quantum dissipative systems

Answer (score 0):

I followed Ian's suggestion of splitting the integral and, although I am still unable to justify rigorously every point, I think I eventually came up with the correct answer. First of all, the asymptotics of my integral seems to be:

$\psi(t,\Omega)\underset{t\to+\infty}{\simeq}\left(\mathrm{pv}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}\omega\,\frac{\Phi(\omega)}{\Omega-\omega}-\mathrm{i}\pi\Phi(\Omega)\right)\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\Omega t}$

To get this result, you split the integral:

$\psi(t,\Omega)=\lim_{\delta\to0^+}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\Omega t}\int_{|\omega-\Omega|>\delta}\mathrm{d}\omega\,\frac{\Phi(\omega)}{\Omega-\omega}+\int_{|\omega-\Omega|>\delta}\mathrm{d}\omega\,\frac{\Phi(\omega)\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\omega t}}{\Omega-\omega}+\int_{|\omega-\Omega|<\delta}\mathrm{d}\omega\,\Phi(\omega)\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\omega t}-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\Omega t}}{\omega-\Omega}\right)$

The real part of the asymptotics obviously comes from the first term in this development. The imaginary part comes from the second one, I still need to work a bit to prove this rigorously though. Finally, the third term should vanish, I did not prove it properly but this shouldn't be too difficult to do for someone more literate than I am in this field.